# Installing SET (Social Engineering Toolkit) but no setup.py program anywhere

Tags: tools

I have been trying to figure out why the toolkit is not displaying the setup.py program like it says everywhere to do. Am I missing a step somewhere?

[image: Here's whats in the set file, as you see there is no setup.py]

Edit: I already have done the pip install -r requirements.txt step. I even went into the actual set folder, theres nothig in there that has the setup.py program. I've been following videos, and even the actual steps. To no avail, is there anything else im doing wrong

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu!  Right now, your question lacks any helpful description. The good thing is, you can simply [edit] your question and include as much description as you like. Please take the time to explain what you are doing where you hit a problem. Please read [about] and [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

pip3 -r install requirements.txt
after that, try to see setoolkit directory or the other. that should be a  setup.py in there.
and then run python setup.py

or if you confused, you can read the README.md with command "cat README.md"
hope this helpful